# Reference for the set of orders of its elements

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

I am looking for a reference for the maximal order of an element in PSL(2, $q$), where $q$ is prime power.

Comment: Could you perhaps give a bit more background or motivation to this question?

Answer (score 1):

A standard reference for this type of results is

Bertram Huppert: *Endliche Gruppen I*, Band 134 der *Grundlehren der
mathematischen Wissenschaften*, 1967, Springer-Verlag.

However I don't have that book at hand, so I cannot check.
Another source you might wish to check is

Jean Dieudonne: *La Geometrie des Groupes Classiques*,
Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete 5(1963).

Comment: I have edited my answer, giving you some hints where to look. However
I don't have the books at hand, so I cannot check.